# c# - How to get the value of the defaultDatabase?

Tags: .net, web-config, c#-2.0

My web.config has the line

```
<dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="ValueIWant"/>
```

that lists the name of default database connection string to use.  How can I get that name from within c#?

sudo code:

```
string info = getDefaultDatabase();
console.WriteLine(info);
```

would print `ValueIWant`.

Thanks

Comment: I think you mean **pseudo** code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the config value is is a custom configuration section, then you need to get the section via ConfigurationManager.GetSection():

```
MyCustomConfigSection config = (MyConstomConfigSection)
                               ConfigurationManager.GetSection(
                                 "MyCustomConfigSectionName"
                                 ) ;
```

And how the desired value is referenced from that is entirely dependent on your custom config section widget.

Comment: dataConfiguration is the section, defaultDatabase an an attribute on the section tag. any idea how to get the attribute value from the section?

Comment: Then your all set:  replace "MyCustomConfigSectionName with "dataConfiguration" in the above example, and downcast the returned configuration section instance to its concrete subtype. Then do the needful to get the desired value from that object. Not knowing any of the implementation details of your custom config section, We can't really give you any more detailed advice, other than if it's a stock AppSettings-like section, you can probably get the value by name via its indexer, thus: `string value = customSectionInstance[ "myDesiredValue" ] ;`.

Comment: Nicholas, its not really a custom section. It the database stuff to connect to the sql server. I'm just trying to get the name of the default connection string.

Comment: If it is in the <ConnectionStrings> element, then you do it the obvious way: `myConnectString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringKey].ConnectionString ;`. Those are the two default sections exposed by ConfigurationManager. Everything else is a "custom section" referenced via GetSection(). The <configSections> element at the beginning of the config file or further up the config hierarchy will tell you the type of the config section handler.

Answer (score -1):

If it's in the  section:

```
string defaultDbName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ "DefaultDatabase" ] ;
```

should do it. The return value is null if the config value isn't found.

Comment: This is returning null. That  from my web.config is not in the appSettings section of the web.config.

Comment: See my new answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797681/c-how-to-get-the-value-of-the-defaultdatabase/4797785#4797785